# Bluemix Secure Gateway : About TLS connection between client and on-prem server

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have question, suppose server side is setup to connect via TLS (v1.0 or later), and the client uses the library so that it can connect via TLS.

```
 [client] - TLS -> [on-prem server]
```

So the connection is secured (encrypted). Now, we move this application to Bluemix, and uses Secure Gateway.

```
 [client] -> [sg host] --- ssl --> [sg host] --> [on-prem server]
```

In this case, do I need to setup to use "Server Side TLS" ? Or just using TCP is fine ?  Just using TCP seems to work all right.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For the connection to be secured (encrypted), you have to setup to use Server Side TLS.